# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - loop

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom, html-parser

I started to play Simple HTML Doom Parser and I have some trouble:

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="players">
    <ul class="dane">
        <li>
            <div class="name">Messi</div>
            <div class="value">Barcelona</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="name">Ronaldo</div>
            <div class="value">Madryt</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="clubs">
    <ul class="dane">
        <li>
            <div class="name">Barcelona</div>
            <div class="value">Hiszpania</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="name">Madryt</div>
            <div class="value">Hiszpania</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="trenerzy">
    <ul class="dane">
        <li>
            <div class="name">Ernesto Valverde</div>
            <div class="value">Barcelona</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="name">Madryt</div>
            <div class="value">Zidane</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My PHP code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://');

$articles = array();
foreach($html->find('ul.dane') as $article) {
    $item['name']     = $article->find('div.name',0)->plaintext;
    $item['value']    = $article->find('div.value',0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

The data it receives is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] =>                   Messi               
            [value] =>                      Barcelona               
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] =>                   Barcelona               
            [value] =>                      Hiszpania               
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] =>                   Ernesto Valverde                
            [value] =>                      Barcelona               
        )
```

It receives data from the data class ul.dane but only 1 record, how can I do to get everything that is on the page?

I know I'm missing a loop somewhere, but I have a problem finding wher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to

1. Find all `ul.dane` elements
2. **Inside each ul, search for `li` elements**
3. Inside each li, search for `div.name` and `div.value` elements

In that case the problem with your code is that you forgot to find each `li` element inside each `ul`, which would be step 2. Try this:

```
foreach($html->find('ul.dane') as $ul) {
    foreach($ul->find('li') as $article){
        $item['name']     = $article->find('div.name',0)->plaintext;
        $item['value']    = $article->find('div.value',0)->plaintext;
        $articles[] = $item;
    }
}
```